# JavaScript : MimeType & application/pdf

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I'm working on a local serv with wamp, and i've tested this on chrome & firefox
Here is my js function :

```
fileDrop.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileInput = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    var mimeType = fileInput[0].type;
    console.log(mimeType);
}, false);
```

The console.log show me "application/pdf" when the dropped file is a pdf, it also shows "image/jpg" when its a jpg etc..

BUT, when the file dropped is a **zip**, the console.log return an empty "" .

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks you

Comment: Doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong. If the browser (probably the OS) doesn't know the mime type for zip files, well, it doesn't.

Comment: An empty string means that the type is not known. MIME type identification is usually done by a simple mapping from some characteristic of the file name (like the extension) or perhaps file metadata.

Comment: when i delete the preventDefault function, here is what i got in the console : Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "file:///C:/Desktop/cv%20motivation/cvMotivation.zip".